# Error while trying to create new element

Tags: javascript, html

I use the following code and I got error when I do appendChild

```
$('#tra').on('click', function() {
    transpile(source.val())

// ...
var display = $('#display');
diff.forEach(function(part) {

 var span = document.createElement('span');
        span.style.color = color;
        span.appendChild(document
            .createTextNode(part.value));
        display.appendChild(span);
```

In the last code I got error:

> main.js:42 Uncaught TypeError: display.appendChild is not a function ,what it can be?

in the index.html I've the display as follows

Comment: have you tried `display.append(span)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, check if your `#display` element exists in your document (DOM).

Second, there is no `appendChild` method in jQuery, so you should use:

```
display.append(span)
```

Or

```
$(span).appendTo(display);
```

Otherwise, if you want to use `appendChild` anyway, you'd use:

```
display[0].appendChild(span);
```

Or by using [$.get](https://api.jquery.com/get/) method:

```
display.get(0).appendChild(span);
```

Comment: Thanks but its not working I dont see the values ,any idea why?

Comment: it seems that when I use <pre id="display"></pre> its working and when I use <textarea id="display"></textarea> it doesnt , any idea why ?

Comment: You cannot append other elements into `textarea`'s.

Answer (score 2):

Your `display` variable is a jQuery object. It has a `.append()` method that should be fine for what you need.

```
display.append(span);
```

If you want to use the JavaScript DOM function `.appendChild()` instead, you need to extract the DOM element from display first:

```
display.get(0).appendChild(span);
```

Comment: when I tried display.get(0).append(span) I got error main.js:42 Uncaught TypeError: display.get(...).append is not a function...any idea?

Comment: `append` is not a function within the DOM scope.

Comment: Sorry, of course the second one was .appendChild(). Editing now.

Comment: @shopiaT try not to mix selecting DOM elements both ways -*pure javascript and jQuery*- together, stick to one of them, and keep in mind some -*IMHO, most of them*- jQuery functions won't work if you don't apply them on jQuery objects `$(selector)`

Comment: it seems that when I use <pre id="display"></pre> its working and when I use <textarea id="display"></textarea> it doesnt , any idea why ?

Comment: That's because a `textarea` should not contain HTML elements (like your `span`), just text. If you need to find a way around this I suggest asking a new question, though.